# Oracle apex form multiply two values and populate field

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form that has a "Miles Traveled Field", which is filled out by the user, as well as "Rate".

Then I'd like a calculation to happen Miles Traveled * Rate which should populate the field "Amount".

How can I achieve this in apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To make calculation on page, without server - you can use Dynamic Actions (Javascript). On a page with "Page properties", click "+" in "Dynamic Actions" section, then pass steps:

   - Identification: enter a name for action
   - When: `Event` - firing event type (click, change, set focus...), `Selection type` and `Item` - item, where user have to click (change, set focus...), and conditions
   - True action: you need to select action type "Execute JavaScript Code". In a field for code input you need to enter something like this:

   `$v('P_ITEM_NAME_FOR_Miles_Traveled') * $v('P_ITEM_NAME_FOR_Rate');`
2. There are number ways to make execution on a server side (dynamic action, process, etc), but in this case it is not appropriate. I can describe later if you need.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry we have referenced you here at work many times since you are the apex guru.